Referenced Blazor component is null
Consider the following Blazor code:
<Foo @ref="foo">
    <Bar @ref="bar"/>
</Foo>

<button @onclick="() => LoadBar("some data")">Click</button>

@code {
    private Bar bar = null!;
    
    private void LoadBar(string data)
    {
        bar.SetData(data) // bar is null
        foo.SetVisible(true); // foo is not null, but exception already thrown
    }
}

When I click the button, I want it to call LoadBar and pass some data to the referenced Bar instance, but the instance is always null. I'm not sure why, although it may be to do with the way it's rendered by Foo; i.e. if isVisible is false in Foo, then Bar will not be rendered.
What sort of approaches does Blazor provide for this scenario?

An [MRE] would help. You mention IsVisible, so there's more functionality that you're showing.  "What sort of approaches does Blazor provide for this scenario?"  Capturing component references and then calling methods on them is not normally the best approach,  but with so little to go on, it's hard to answer that question.

Your assumption is right. bar will be null if it's not rendered yet. Can you share a minimal reproducible example with definitions of Foo and Bar that describe what you're trying to do?

This is close to a mre but some parts are missing. Notably, does Foo render its ChildContent?
